# Break Base Url in part

Tags: magento2

i have written below code to get base url of my site.

```
var linkUrl = url.build('');
console.log(linkUrl);
```

and its return ulr like https://mywebsit.com/en https://mywebsit.com/fr https://mywebsit.com/nl

i want extract 2nd part in url after / like en fr and nl how i achieved this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using below code:**

```
var linkUrl = url.build('');

linkUrl = linkUrl.substring(linkUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

console.log(linkUrl);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
var linkUrl = url.build('');

linkUrl = linkUrl.split('/');

console.log(linkUrl[1]);
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: It will work please once check that your js file is updated in pub/static or in frontend? If it is updated then please share the errors in console

Comment: i have attached images in my question description

Comment: You missed to add var linkUrl = url.build(''); please copy the whole answer and let me know

Comment: Is it working for you?    var linkUrl = url.build('');

linkUrl = linkUrl.substring(linkUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

console.log(linkUrl);

Comment: now error gone but console is blank whne i type 0 its show / in log

Comment: Are you sure your _https://mywebsit.com/nl this was working as output before. If yes only add the code 
                                 linkUrl = linkUrl.substring(linkUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

console.log(linkUrl);

Comment: So you want only country code from this abc.com/nl/en/checkout/#shipping url right?

Comment: Updated my answer if you want countrycode

Comment: still same it tried

Comment: working sorry fine now